# Fastlane Gym configuration Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: ios, code-signing, fastlane

I want to setup fastlane for my project. I got few targets (app, watchkit app and watchkit extension) plus few third party projects in my workspace.

My problem is that I can't download a build from crashlytics when I upload it with fastlane, but I can do it when I archive build manually.

This is my fastlane

```
lane :beta do

sh 'bash ./update_version.sh'

gym(scheme: "MyApp", 
  workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
  configuration: "Ad Hoc Distribution")

crashlytics(
  api_token: "d543d4a5b27009b...",
  build_secret: "fafb26aa69fa...",
  groups:"myapp-team",
  notifications: true
)
end
```

I add configuration property for gym, because it use Release by default, and I want to use Ad Hoc configuration for distribution, because all Ad Hoc profiles set up in this configuration.

As far as I understand, gym command with configuration property will set Ad Hoc configuration for all targets and projects inside the workspace. Right?

I tried to emulate what fastlane will do and I set `Atchive` -> `Build Configuration` -> `Ad Hoc` manually in all targets' and projects' Schemes and archive my project. After that I upload this archive to crashlytics and was able to download this build. So, my profiles are fine and they include my device.

How to check setup fastlane to use exactly same configurations/profiles?

Thank you.

**UPD**

One more additional check, which should help with some details.

I archived project with Xcode, then create IPA file and run this command from fabric's doc - https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html

```
/path/to/Crashlytics.framework/submit API_KEY BUILD_SECRET \
-ipaPath path.to/my.ipa \
-groupAliases my-team \
-notifications YES
```

After that I was able to download build.

Thanks for Todd from fastlane.

**UPD 2**

This is the last part of my fastlane output

```
...
Copying myapp/Resources/sound/connection_found.wav
[09:33:52]: ▸ Copying myapp/Resources/sound/connection_lost.wav
[09:33:52]: ▸ Copying myapp.strings
[09:33:52]: ▸ Copying myapp/Resources/sound/kicked.wav
[09:33:56]: ▸ Processing myapp-Info.plist
[09:33:56]: ▸ Generating 'myapp.app.dSYM'
[09:33:59]: ▸ Copying /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dfrdqdmlsgvypadklcuzikqgrnzs/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Ad\ Hoc\ Distribution-iphoneos/myapp\ WatchKit\ Extension.appex
[09:33:59]: ▸ skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dfrdqdmlsgvypadklcuzikqgrnzs/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/myapp WatchKit Extension.appex/myapp WatchKit App.app/_WatchKitStub/WK
[09:33:59]: ▸ skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dfrdqdmlsgvypadklcuzikqgrnzs/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/myapp WatchKit Extension.appex/myapp WatchKit App.app/myapp WatchKit App
[09:33:59]: ▸ skipping copy phase strip, binary is code signed: /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dfrdqdmlsgvypadklcuzikqgrnzs/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/myapp WatchKit Extension.appex/myapp WatchKit Extension
[09:33:59]: ▸ Running script 'Run Script'
[09:33:59]: ▸ Touching myapp.app
[09:33:59]: ▸ Signing /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-dfrdqdmlsgvypadklcuzikqgrnzs/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/myapp.app
[09:34:00]: ▸ Touching myapp.app.dSYM
[09:34:00]: ▸ Archive Succeeded
[09:34:00]: Generated plist file with the following values:
[09:34:00]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
[09:34:00]: ▸ {
[09:34:00]: ▸   "method": "app-store",
[09:34:00]: ▸   "uploadSymbols": true,
[09:34:00]: ▸   "uploadBitcode": false
[09:34:00]: ▸ }
[09:34:00]: ▸ -----------------------------------------
[09:34:00]: $ /usr/bin/xcrun /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.48.0/gym/lib/assets/wrap_xcodebuild/xcbuild-safe.sh -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist '/var/folders/z7/3krkc5211ng2c090_qhd2tlm0000gn/T/gym_config20170726-23446-a2yb0t.plist' -archivePath /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-07-26/myapp\ 2017-07-26\ 09.32.18.xcarchive -exportPath '/var/folders/z7/3krkc5211ng2c090_qhd2tlm0000gn/T/gym_output20170726-23446-hafxer'
[09:34:08]: Compressing 2 dSYM(s)
[09:34:08]: $ cd '/Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-07-26/myapp 2017-07-26 09.32.18.xcarchive/dSYMs' && zip -r '/Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Desktop/myapp/myapp-ios-client/myapp.app.dSYM.zip' *.dSYM
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp WatchKit Extension.appex.dSYM/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp WatchKit Extension.appex.dSYM/Contents/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp WatchKit Extension.appex.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist (deflated 51%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp WatchKit Extension.appex.dSYM/Contents/Resources/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp WatchKit Extension.appex.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp WatchKit Extension.appex.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/myapp WatchKit Extension (deflated 64%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp.app.dSYM/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp.app.dSYM/Contents/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp.app.dSYM/Contents/Info.plist (deflated 52%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/ (stored 0%)
[09:34:09]: ▸ updating: myapp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/myapp (deflated 69%)

[09:34:09]: Successfully exported and compressed dSYM file
[09:34:09]: Successfully exported and signed the ipa file:
[09:34:09]: /Users/evgeniitrapeznikov/Desktop/myapp/myapp-ios-client/myapp.ipa
[09:34:09]: -------------------------
[09:34:09]: --- Step: crashlytics ---
[09:34:09]: -------------------------
[09:34:09]: Uploading the build to Crashlytics Beta. Time for some ☕️.
[09:34:26]: Build successfully uploaded to Crashlytics Beta 
[09:34:26]: Visit https://fabric.io/_/beta to add release notes and notify testers.
[09:34:26]: -------------------
[09:34:26]: --- Step: slack ---
[09:34:26]: -------------------
[09:34:28]: Successfully sent Slack notification

+------+---------------------+-------------+
|             fastlane summary             |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action              | Time (in s) |
+------+---------------------+-------------+
| 1    | Verifying required  | 0           |
|      | fastlane version    |             |
| 2    | default_platform    | 0           |
| 3    | bash                | 0           |
|      | ./update_version.sh |             |
| 4    | gym                 | 118         |
| 5    | crashlytics         | 16          |
| 6    | slack               | 1           |
+------+---------------------+-------------+

[09:34:28]: fastlane.tools finished successfully
```

Comment: I have just added gym with the below 3 configuration. It works fine. It uploads to hockey app perfectly.                          export_method: "ad-hoc",
                     output_directory: "./Hockeybuild",
                     scheme: Array Of BundleId

Comment: Thanks Eugene, Todd from Fabric/fastlane here. Can you let me know if you are manually setting the provisioning profile? Usually this type of issue is caused by the wrong provisioning profile being used at signing. Can you provide the full output of your run of the Crashlytics action to upload the beta build.  Also, let me know if you see the same issue with the submit script here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/build-tools.html?

Comment: @ToddBurner thank you for your comment here. I understand that the problem in wrong profiles. Yes, I set all provisioning profiles manually (without Automatically manage signing checked). Do you want me to archive project in xcode, then create IPA file and run this script in terminal? Or I should add this as the step in fastlane with sh command?

Comment: @ToddBurner I archived it with xcode and send it with a command from your link. Build is available for download. For details, see my update, please.

Comment: @ToddBurner just added log from fastlane. Hope, this is helpful

Comment: @ToddBurner I fixed it. I just added export_method: "ad-hoc" to gym. Thanks to @mpirri!  https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/9854

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just added `export_method: "ad-hoc"` to gym and it works.